# Pyinstaller app created on mac and cant share with Windows Users

Tags: python, windows, macos, exe, pyinstaller

Hello I have currently make a .app that runs perfectly I have shared it with my friends that use mac and it runs perfectly  It is a PyQt5 app  that I created with pyinstaller   the commands I used to make it is:

pyinstaller --icon=(.....).icns --onefile --noconsole -n(.....) (the .py script)  It compiles perfectly and creates the app with the icon image and opens up and all that I am able to compress it into a zip file and email it to my mac users which also runs for them without them having to install anything

But I have some window user friends that I want to share with and the .app obviously wont work (I tried to change the file name and replaces the .app with .exe) and tried to send that which doesn't work they try and run it and it says

"this app can't run on your pc  To Find a version for your pc check with the software publisher"

and so I tried to compile a new app  but with -F in the pyinstaller thing added to the ling of code I use in the terminal then a bunch of stuff runs in the terminal that says .exe and all that and when I drag it onto my desktop it is a .app and so I change it to a .exe again and try and share it with my  window user friends and I get the same error

"this app can't run on your pc  To Find a version for your pc check with the software publisher"

Can anyone help me out im really trying to get a way on how to make it run on windows computer please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a Windows app the script need to be compiled in a PC with Windows. The same for Mac and Linux. This is in the [manual](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/):

> PyInstaller is tested against Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux. However, it is not a cross-compiler: to make a Windows app you run PyInstaller in Windows; to make a Linux app you run it in Linux, etc. PyInstaller has been used successfully with AIX, Solaris, and FreeBSD, but is not tested against them.